# ping multiple IP's from mysql using bash?

Tags: networking, bash, scripts, mysql, ping

How can I ping a list of IPs found in a mysql database from bash?

I have a table called nics containing these fields:

- id
- user_id
- machine_id
- mac
- ipv4
- ipv6
- dns
- icmp => used as a binary (0=disable, 1=enable). This will tell the script if it should ping the ip
- created
- modified

Comment: +1 to get you on your way. What @steeldriver means is there is check box under your question that says "answer your own question" click it and you will be given an answer window,. Cut and paste the bulk of your question into it. Then rephrase your question into "How can I ping sites from an MariaDB SQL table containing these rows and fields..."

Comment: Hopefully this does the trick. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: There is a lot to learn navigating this site. Have another 10 points for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I built my monitoring app (the portion that uses ICMP messages to retrieve alive host). In my case, the mysql server (MariaDB) is running on the same machine as the app.

In this cron, I only use 2 of the fields (ipv4 and icmp). The icmp field is used to determine if this nics should be monitored or not.

here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#variables

SQL_U=username
SQL_P=password
SQL_D=database

mysql -u ${SQL_U} -p${SQL_P} -D ${SQL_D} -e "SELECT ipv4 FROM nics WHERE icmp=1;" | while IFS=$'\t' read ipv4; 
do 
    if [ "$ipv4" != "ipv4" ]; then
        PING_IP=$ipv4
        PING_LOSS=0
        PING_TEST=$(fping -c 1 -p 20 ${PING_IP} | awk '{ print $1 }')
        if [ "$PING_TEST" = "$PING_IP" ]; then
            PING_LOSS=1
        fi
        PING_C=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        mysql -u ${SQL_U} -p${SQL_P} -D ${SQL_D} -e "INSERT INTO ping (ipv4, loss, created, modified) VALUES ('${PING_IP}', '${PING_LOSS}', '${PING_C}', '${PING_C}');"
    fi
done
```

All results are inserted into a table called ping. In which I insert the ip, the ping result in binary (0=loss, 1=received), created and modified date. With this script, I am able to monitore about 100 ips (for now) every 5min and collect statistic.Bare in mind that I am using fping instead of ping on a debian stretch machine. Due to it's many features.